# Prove that a tetrahedral angle can be intersected by a plane in such a way that the cross section is a parallelogram.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, 3d, polyhedra

### Exercise:

> Prove that a tetrahedral angle can be intersected by a plane in such a way that the cross section is a parallelogram.

---

### Attempt:

Draw an arbitrary parallelogram $ABCD$ on an arbitrary plane $P$.

Pick every point $S$ not on $P$.

$SABCD$ is a tetrahedral angle with vertex $S$ with a cross section of a parallelogram $ABCD$.

Draw another arbitrary parallelogram $EFGH$ not intersecting $P$.

Pick every point $T$ on $P$.

$TEFGH$ is a tetrahedral angle with vertex $T$ with a cross section of a parallelogram $EFGH$.

Every point $S$ and $T$ covers all points.

So, every point can be a vertex of a tetrahedral angle that has a cross section of a parallelogram.

---

### Request:

I realized my attempt doesn't exactly prove what is asked, so it isn't valid. However, I've share it anyways to show that I have tried to do something about this exercise, and maybe I had the right idea.

I think that the most reasonable proof would be proof-by-construction, however I'm not sure how to go about such proof. Hints and solutions are welcome.

Comment: A vector proof is straightforward. Let the angle have the origin as its vertex, and let the edges be rays through points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ (with $A := (x_A, y_A, z_A)$, etc). Define $A^\prime := a A$, $B^\prime := b B$, $C^\prime := c C$, $D^\prime := d D$ for some $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. Then $\square A^\prime B^\prime C^\prime D^\prime$ is a parallelogram if and only if $$A^\prime - B^\prime = D^\prime - C^\prime$$ Comparing coordinates gives three equations; and you can solve for, say, $a$, $b$, $c$ in terms of $d$ and the $xyz$s.

Comment: @Blue -- I trust you're correct, but I'm not familiar with vector geometry. :)

Comment: You'll get to know vectors soon enough. :)  In the meantime, I'll note that the solution to my formulation reveals this relation: $$\frac{a}{|OBCD|} = \frac{b}{|OACD|} = \frac{c}{|OABD|} = \frac{d}{|OABC|}$$ where $|WXYZ|$ is the volume of a tetrahedron with the given vertices. If we take the original $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ to be coplanar, then those volumes are proportional to the base-areas on the common plane, so that $$\frac{a}{|\triangle BCD|}=\frac{b}{|\triangle ACD|}=\frac{c}{|\triangle ABD|}=\frac{d}{|\triangle ABC|}$$ Perhaps you can leverage this observation in a vector-free proof.